# Need to create background with rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to create background with rounded corners, but inside should be transparent and outside should be white.

Its background for camera view but I cant combine those shapes.

Issue is that I cant combine rectangle with rounded corners and solid block shape.

rounded corner xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/white" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_2"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_2"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_2"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_2"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

outer background xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

final background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/outer_background" />

</layer-list>
```

Expectation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>         <item
>             android:left="6dp"
>             android:right="6dp">
>             <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>                 android:shape="rectangle">
>                 <stroke
>                     android:width="20dp"
>                     android:color="#ffffff" />
>             </shape>
>         </item>
>         <item
>             android:bottom="10dp"
>             android:left="20dp"
>             android:right="20dp"
>             android:top="10dp">
>             <shape android:shape="rectangle">
>                 <stroke android:width="10dp"/>
>                 <corners
>                     android:radius="10dp" />
>                 <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
>             </shape>
>         </item>
>     </layer-list>
> ```